# Linux shell awk: displaying different column values when condition met

Tags: linux, shell, awk

How can I use both conditional and loop statement inside the awk command to convert a file with special value to a different value like "Error", and not doing any subtraction, instead just display the converted new value like "Error" as the output?

1. if none of the column value (except column 1 which stays the same in the final output) is equal to the special value like "11111", I use an awk command like following:

   ```
   awk -F, '{print $1,$2,($3-$2),($4-$2),($5-$2),($6-$2),($7-$2),($8-$2),($9-$2),($10-$2),($11-$2),($12-$2),($13-$2),($14-$1)} ' all.cvs
   ```
2. if the column value = the special value, then no need to do "-$2", just display a new value like "Error"

Basically I want: x means column value for column #2 to #14

- if $2 (column #2) = 11111

  ```
  set $2="Error"
  ```
- for $3 to $14 (column #3 to #14) if the column value is <> 11111

  ```
  $x=$x-$2
  ```
- if the column value =11111

  ```
  $x=Error
  ```
- At the end, the output will still show 14 columns including original #1 column value and converted/calculated new values for column #2 to #14

I have a file (all.cvs) like following:

- 14 fields
- each line may contains a field with a value like "11111" (or any string value)
- each column separated by ","
- total number of lines is 90

---

```
$cat all.cvs

A,11111,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 

B,1,2,3,4,5,6,11111,8,9,10,11,12,13 

C,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11111,11,12,13 
....
```

Comment: What happens to columns 3-14 if column 2 is error?  Copy unchanged?  Set to Error?  Subtract 11111 from it anyway?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your questions. if #2 is set to error, and any columns in columns 3-14 has value of 11111, then set it/them to Error too, no subtraction. Subtraction only happens if both column #2 and other column are <> 11111.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v flag_value=11111 '
  {subtract = $2}
  $2 == flag_value {$2 = "Error"; subtract = 0}
  {
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i == flag_value ? "Error" : $i - subtract)
    print
  }
'
```

Comment: Having the same problem as the 1st approach provided by beny23.  It didn't convert all columns having value of "11111" to "Error".

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for your update. It works! Pardon my limited knowledge on awk, do you mind explain your script line by line?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

```
$ awk -F, '
{ 
  printf("%s", $1); 
  s=($2 != 11111 ? $2 : 0); 
  printf(", %s", ($2 != 11111 ? $2 : "Error")); 
  for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) 
    printf (", %d", ($i != 11111 ? ($i - s) : "Error")); 
  printf("\n"); 
}' all.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your conditional blocks before your default block. Put `next` at the end of each in order to resume processing with the next line.